# Transmitting through IRDA as if its a native serial port. Possible?

Tags: serial, infrared, rs232, data

I'm currently making a lazertag project that utilizes the standard UART data format for data I/O.

Before I go make up another circuit board that connects a photo-transistor that senses a laser beam to a PC serial port via MAX232 IC, would it be possible that I can directly send the beam to an IRDA serial port of my laptop and have the laptop correctly read the data?

If not, then I guess I'll need to change the output to infrared-only first (using an IR emitter).

Also, would the standard serial port data be accepted on IRDA natively, or do I need special drivers to make it accept standard serial input?

I want to do real-time tests of my project and if the IRDA on the computer will make results bad then I'll just go with standard serial.

For clarification, standard serial input here means data in the 8N1 format (low bit to start data, then 8 data bits of data, then high bit to end data).

Comment: IRDA has a protocol that is different from the serial port

Answer (score 1):

[Here are some details on how IRDA behaves](https://superuser.com/questions/160297/how-to-use-irda-adapter-as-serial-port).  If you were going IRDA to IRDA, it would be transparent.  However, unless you're planning to implement the IRDA protocol in your laser, it's not going to work.